# Finding index of given character in a string in Python with some default Parameter

Tags: python, string, function, search, nameerror

This might be a silly question and perhaps might be one of those easiest question on SO. Consider the following code which tries to find the index of given character in a string:

```
def find(s ,ch, start=0): 
    index = start 
    while index <= end: 
        if s[index] == ch:
            return index 
        index = index + 1 
    return -1
print(find("apple","p"))
```

This works fine. Now, in this code I want to add a default Parameter `end` which will tell the function till what length of string, we have to search in the given string. Like this:

```
def find(s, ch, start=0,end=len(s)): 
    index = start 
    while index <= end: 
        if s[index] == ch:
             return index 
        index = index + 1 
    return -1
    
print(find("apple","p"))
```

However, when I run this code, I get the error in the line 1 of the above code:

`NameError: Name s is not defined`

I tried to read something about this in some textbook. I found that when function is defined, `s` is still undefined (For which I have no idea about why this is a case). Hence, len(s) is undefinable.

I know that there is a built in function which implements this but I want to write my own algorithm to do that.

Can anyone help or give hint?

Comment: Default arguments are evaluated once at definition time, so there's no way to have a dynamic value for end based upon s.  You could have default `end = None`, then have `if end is None: end = len(s)` within the function.

Answer (score 1):

A more pythonic choice for iterating a list would be the `for` loop since it is simpler and easier to read:

```
def find(s, ch):
    index = None
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        if s[i] == ch:
            index = i + 1 
            return (index)
            
print(find("auhkle","a"))
print(find("auhkle","h"))
print(find("auhkle","e"))
```

Output:

```
1
3
6
```